# tcp server blocking read in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I want to implement a simple TCP server with blocking read, that receives messages sent from a client character by character until a separator. Once a message is received, it has to wait until the next message appears. Here is my pseudocode:

```
// Messages sent from the client
char *message1 = "mssg1\n"
char *message2 = "mssg2\n"

// On server side
char buffer;
char completeMessage[5]

while(1){

    while(buffer != '\n'){
        recv(sock, &buffer, 1, 0); // 1 is the read size

        if(buffer != '\n') {
            printf("buffer: %c\n", buffer);
            completeMessage[n] = buffer;
            count ++;  
        }
        else{
            printf("Complete message: %s\n", completeMessage);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is the following:

```
buffer: m
buffer: s
buffer: s
buffer: g
buffer: 1
Complete message: mssg1
buffer:
buffer:
buffer:
buffer:
buffer:
buffer:
// Error due to buffer overflow
```

I don't know why recv instead of waiting for the next message character (blocking read), it continues reading blank spaces. My questions are the following:

- Is recv really a socket blocking read function?
- Is there something wrong or missing in the code?
- Any other suggestions for implementing this?

Comment: Re "*Is recv really a socket blocking read function?*", yes, unless you made the handle non-blocking.

Comment: Re "*Is there something wrong or missing in the code?*", You're not checking what `read` returns. `0` indicates EOF, and `-1` indicates an error. Also, you don't check how full your buffer is

Comment: `recv()` returns a value. You could use that.

Comment: You're not adding a null terminator to `completeMessage` before you print it with `%s`.

Comment: Most likely your client code is sending an entire buffer with extra NUL characters after the newline, so you are reading those NULs.  But as you don't show the client code, it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is recv really a socket blocking read function?*

Yes, unless you made the handle non-blocking.

> *Is there something wrong or missing in the code?*,

- You're not checking what `recv` returns. `0` indicates EOF, and `-1` indicates an error.
- You don't check how full your buffer is, so you risk buffer overflows.
- You're not terminating the string in `completeMessage` with a NUL as required by `printf %s`.

> *Any other suggestions for implementing this?*

You shouldn't read a character at a time!

---

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE (64*1024)

char* extract_string(const char* start, const char* end) {
    size_t len = end - start;
    char* dst = malloc(len+1);
    if (dst == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memcpy(dst, src, len);
    dst[len] = '\0';
    return dst;
}

{
    char buf_start[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char* buf_end = buf_start + BUFFER_SIZE;
    char* window_start = buf_start;
    char* window_end = buf_start;
    while (1) {
        if (window_end == buf_end) { // No more space.
            fprintf(stderr, "Overly large message");
            return 0;
        }

        ssize_t rv = recv(sock, window_end, buf_end-window_end, 0);
        if (rv == -1) {  // Error.
            perror("recv");
            return 0;
        }

        if (rv == 0) {  // EOF.
            return 1;
        }

        while (rv--) {
            if (*(window_end++) == '\n') {
                char* msg = extract_string(window_start, window_end-1);  // Excl LF.
                if (msg == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
                    return 0;
                }

                // Do something with msg
                printf("Complete message: %s\n", msg);
                free(msg);

                window_start = window_end;
            }
        }

        memmove(buf_start, window_start, window_end-window_start);
        window_end -= (window_start - buf_start);
        window_start = buf_start;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Switched to `recv`. Comments deleted.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a number of problems with your code, namely that you are ignoring the return value of `recv()`, you are not null-terminating your `buffer` before printing it, and you are not protecting yourself from a buffer overflow.

Try something more like this instead:

```
char ch, *tmp, *message = NULL;
int ret, length = 0, allocated = 0;

while (1)
{
    ret = recv(sock, &ch, 1, 0);
    if (ret <= 0)
    {
        if (ret < 0)
            printf("Read error: %d\n", errno); // or WSAGetLastError() on Windows
        else
            printf("Client disconnected\n");
        break;
    }

    if (ch == '\n')
    {
        if ((length > 0) && (message[length-1] == '\r'))
          --length;

        printf("Complete message: '%.*s'\n", length, message);    

        length = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ch: %c\n", ch);

        if (length == allocated)
        {
            if (length >= 5000) // some max length of your choosing...
            {
                printf("Message length too large!\n");
                break;
            }

            // just for example. You should use a more robust growth algorithm in production code...
            tmp = (char*) realloc(message, allocated + 10);
            if (!tmp)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
                break;
            }

            message = tmp;
            allocated += 10;
        }

        message[length] = ch;
        ++length;
    }
}

free(message);
```

Alternatively, don't read char-by-char.  Read as much data as you can from the socket on any given read and store it all in a growing buffer, and then scan that buffer for complete messages, eg:

```
char *buffer = (char*) malloc(100);
if (!buffer)
{
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
}
else
{
    int ret, offset, remaining, inbuf = 0, allocated = 100;
    char *ptr;

    while (1)
    {
        if (inbuf == allocated)
        {
            if (inbuf >= 5000) // some max length of your choosing...
            {
                printf("Buffer length too large!\n");
                break;
            }

            // just for example. You should use a more robust growth algorithm in production code...
            tmp = (char*) realloc(buffer, allocated + 100);
            if (!tmp)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
                break;
            }

            buffer = tmp;
            allocated += 100;
        }

        ret = recv(sock, buffer+inbuf, allocated-inbuf, 0);
        if (ret <= 0)
        {
            if (ret < 0)
                printf("Read error: %d\n", errno); // or WSAGetLastError() on Windows
            else
                printf("Client disconnected\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("Received: %.*s\n", ret, buffer+inbuf);
        inbuf += ret;

        while (ptr = (char*)memchr(buffer, '\n', inbuf))
        {
            offset = (ptr-buffer);
            if ((offset > 0) && (buffer[offset-1] == '\r'))
                --offset;

            printf("Complete message: '%.s'\n", offset, buffer);    

            ++ptr;
            remaining = (inbuf - (ptr - buffer));
            if (remaining > 0)
                memmove(buffer, ptr, remaining);
            inbuf = remaining;
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
}
```